# Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info at setModule

Tags: ios, react-native

[enter image description here Answere fast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnYSz.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have misunderstood what we do here.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

Remove an Duplicate App folder in your Project...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Go into the project directory and run the following commands

```
rm -rf node_modules
sudo npm i
```